# Excel IF statement to check 2 cells at once

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create an Excel formula which creates a range. This formula checks to make sure `MOI_Range<>"NONE"` and that `USE_90 = "YES"`. The range values will also be kept above `0` and below `100`.

- MOI_Range & USE_90 are dictionary cells that refer to a value.

Here is a VBA code example to help you get a better understanding.

```
IF MOI_Range <> "NONE" AND USE_90 = "YES" Then

Moi_Range

Else

CONCATENATE(IF(M15<0,0,M15), "-",IF(N15>100,100,N15), "%")

EndIf
```

Here is the formula that I attempted that gives an "There's a problem with this formula" message.

```
IF(MOI_Range<>"NONE" AND USE_90="YES",MOI_Range,CONCATENATE(IF(M15<0,0,M15), "-",IF(N15>100,100,N15), "%"))
```

Comment: in your code, you did not close the quote after the word `NONE` on the first line. was that a type on here or in your original code?

Comment: Sorry @MakPo I quickly wrote that up out of the VBA editor to provide a further example. I'll be sure to fix that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AND()` is not done in line:

```
AND(MOI_Range<>"NONE", USE_90="YES")
```

So:

```
IF(AND(MOI_Range<>"NONE", USE_90="YES"),MOI_Range,CONCATENATE(IF(M15<0,0,M15), "-",IF(N15>100,100,N15), "%"))
```